# IO.StreamReader(filename) Sillyness

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, relative-path, streamreader

Why is it that I can't use a relative path for `IO.StreamReader("Resources/file.txt")`?

I'm working with a web app, so obviously the file isn't going to be in the same absolute location between my development machine and the server.

How can I fix my filename path so it finds the file?

For reference, I have a file (relative to the page calling it) at path "Resources/file.txt" but the stupid function is looking in root "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE." And just in case it matters, I'm on .NET 3.5 at the moment.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename) to find the relative path to your file as a string then pass this to IO.StreamReader like so:

```vb
Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(filename))
Dim text As String = DirectCast(sr, IO.TextReader).ReadToEnd() 'gives you text
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because your working folder is not where the web root is, it's where the application is. When developing it's where the Visual Studio application is, on a live server it will be where the IIS application is.

Use a virtual path, and the `Server.MapPath` method to map it to a folder relative to the web root:

```
StreamReader(Server.MapPath("Resources/file.txt"))
```